# Regular Expression that matches any .aspx url

Tags: c#, regex

The text I was going through mentioned that following regular Expression matches any .aspx url:

`@"?i:^.*\.aspx.*$"`

I couldnot understand what `?i:^` did while matching. Pls. explain what part it matches in urls like `http://localhost:2447/Out.aspx`, `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx`.

Comment: Please dont use text-speak, there are many people from all around the world and it may be difficult for some to understand.

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetExtension(new Uri(url).LocalPath)

Comment: best regex for checking file extension is "\b\w+\.(?=aspx)\w+\b" in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?i` means ignore case. Your pattern also has some unneeded fillers. If you only want to check if the string contains `.aspx`, use this:

```
(?i)\.aspx

// Match:
http://localhost:2447/Out.aspx
http://localhost:2447/Out.AsPx/suburl
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx
```